# Xcode 4 'QuartzCore/CIColor.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm running Xcode 4 and trying to follow the steps in Apple's Image Kit Programming Guide (which is written for Xcode 3) on how to work with an Image View and the IKImageView class. I just imported the Quartz and Quartz Core frameworks (from /System/Frameworks directory) to my blank *Cocoa Application* project using *File > Add Files to...* menu, but when I try to **Run** my application I get this error: 
**Lexical or Preprocessor Issue** *'QuartzCore/CIColor.h' file not found*

Does anyone know what could be a reason?

> *Peter Hosey replied*:
>
> You're not supposed to import specific headers directly, and especially not from sub-frameworks (such as Core Image, sub-framework of QuartzCore). Only import a framework's overall header, which usually has the same name as the framework.

I didn't import any specific headers directly, I just choose File>Add Files to... then choose /system/Frameworks and choose two ***folders*** which contain those frameworks, after that they appeared in my project navigator view as they should, but the code wouldn't compile any more. It shows me *NSColor.h* file which is found in the *AppKit framework*, points at this line: *#import*  and says **Lexical or Preprocessor Issue** *'QuartzCore/CIColor.h' file not found*. I have no clue why it wouldn't compile. CI stands for Core Image. I'm now reading a guide on Core Image, maybe this will help. I'd like to post a screenshot but I can't (not enough rights yet).

Comment: The problem you're facing has nothing to do with Core Image specifically, so no amount of reading Core Image documentation will help. Please upload your screenshot directly to imgur.com and edit your question to include the link.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. The problem was that the Guide I used was written for Xcode 3 so when I tried to import/add some frameworks to my project using *File>Add files to project* menu as described it did add those frameworks and I could see them in the project navigator but something went wrong. In Xcode 4 you should use a different way to add/import Frameworks by using the *Project Editor> Summary tab> Linked Frameworks and Libraries> Click "+"* and then choose the Frameworks you need. That fixed the issue. Thank you for your support and being here for me, I appreciate that.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Guide I used was written for Xcode 3 so when I tried to import/add some frameworks to my project using "File>Add files" menu as described, it did add those frameworks and I could see them in the project navigator, but something went wrong. In Xcode 4 you should use a different way to add/import Frameworks by using the Project Editor> Summary tab> Linked Frameworks and Libraries> Click "+" and then choose the Frameworks you need. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I just imported the Quartz and Quartz Core frameworks (from /System/Frameworks directory) to my blank Cocoa Application project using File > Add Files to... menu, …

That's not importing; that's just adding it to the project (and hopefully the target). Importing is what you do with the `#import` directive.

> … but when I try to Run my application I get this error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'QuartzCore/CIColor.h' file not found

You're not supposed to import specific headers directly, and especially not from sub-frameworks (such as Core Image, sub-framework of QuartzCore). Only import a framework's overall header, which usually has the same name as the framework.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Peter. I replied you above.